# Can I insist on having the Goldstone boson as a physical degree of freedom in scalar QED with spontaneous broken $U(1)$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, superconductivity, symmetry-breaking, degrees-of-freedom

We have all learned about the Higgs mechanism in the standard QFT course.  Given a complex scalar $\phi^4$ theory with global $U(1)$ symmetry, when $U(1)$ is spontaneously broken, the phase fluctuation is the associated gapless Goldstone mode.  However, if $U(1)$ is gauged, the would-be Goldstone boson is "eaten" by the gauge field, and we have instead only the massive vector field plus a Higgs mode.

The $R_{\xi}$ gauge treatment of the broken symmetry phase is also designed with this physical picture from the outset.  The Goldstone boson acquires a gauge-dependent mass $\sqrt{\xi} M$ ($M$ is the gauge field mass) and therefore can never be a physically propagating degree of freedom.

If we set the $U(1)$ coupling $e = 0$ so that the vector and scalar decouples, we can recover the charge-neutral result, with the Goldstone boson becomes massless and physical (gauge-independent) again.  But it is an abrupt change; I can't take the limit $e \rightarrow 0$ and see the spectrum of the theory continuously evolves into the $e=0$ case.

--edit--
Well, in terms of just the spectrum you probably can.
I mean I have to switch abruptly from vector to Goldstone for the theoretical description.
--edit--

Now what I am really working on is the Ginzburg-Landau theory of an extreme type-II superconductor, which is exactly the scalar QED in Euclidean 3D (or 2D) with a very small $e$.  If the order parameter is exactly electric neutral, then the low-energy spectrum of the theory is the gapless phase fluctuation all right.  But if we turn on the $U(1)$ coupling just infinitesimally, surely there must be a way to look at the theory so that the low-energy spectrum still resembles the phase fluctuation?

(I mean, suppose you talk to the experimentalists, the phase of the order parameter means a lot more than the third polarization of a photon to them!)